# Count of an exact string in a given string, update count

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am trying to get a count of an exact string in a given string, then find it in a csv file's row and update the count. In detail:

I have a sample string as follows: 
"5 18; 4 00; 4 00; 5 16; 5 16; 5 16; 5 15; 3 19; 3 16; 3 16; 3 15; 3 15;".

The first digit in the string is the day (1-7 where 1 is Monday, 5 is Friday, etc). Second digit after the space is the hour (24 hour. where 18 is 6pm). Each entry is separated by semicolon and space.

I have a master file that holds days (1-7) and hours (00-23). I generate my days and hours as follows:

```
for day in range(1, 8):
    for hour in range(00, 24):
       # Write day + hour, nums.
       writerCommits.writerow([str(day) + " " + str(hour), "0"]); # to write  csv
```

The above for loop generates master.csv:

```
date, count
1 0,0
1 1,0
1 2,0
1 3,0
1 4,0
...
7 19,0
7 20,0
7 21,0
7 22,0
7 23,0
```

total of 169 rows = (7 x 24) + 1 where 1 is the first row/header.

So far so good. I need to update the values in master.csv with count from my string. So everytime 5 18 is found it increments by 1.

If I had this as my sample string: "1 00; 1 00; 1 00; 5 16;". My expected output will be:

```
date, count
1 0,3
...
5 16,1
...
7 23, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `collections.Counter`:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

strs="1 00; 1 00; 1 00; 5 16;"
c=Counter(tuple(map(int,x.split())) for x in strs.split(";") if x.strip())

#c is Counter({(1, 0): 3, (5, 16): 1})
#here I used a tuple (day,hour) as key and item after `,` as value

with open('master.csv', 'rb') as f1,open("newfile.csv","w") as f2:
     spamreader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
     header=next(spamreader)
     f2.write(",".join(header)+'\n')
     for row in spamreader:
         key,val=tuple(map(int,row[0].split())),int(row[1])
         #fetch tuple (day,hour) from the current line
         #val is the value after `,`

         val+=c[key] #new value is count from c + count from csv file

         f2.write("{0},{1}\n".format(" ".join(map(str,key)),val))
```

this will create a new file called `newfile.csv` which now contains:

```
date, count
1 0,3
1 1,0
1 2,0
1 3,0
1 4,0
...
7 19,0
7 20,0
7 21,0
7 22,0
7 23,0
```

Generating the master.csv as a string variable:

```
In [69]: strs="date, count\n"

In [70]: for day in xrange(1,8):
    for hour in xrange(24):
        strs+="{0} {1},{2}\n".format(day,hour,"0")  #use string formatting
   ....:         

In [71]: print strs
date, count
1 0,0
1 1,0
1 2,0
1 3,0
...
7 21,0
7 22,0
7 23,0
```

Comment: This definitely creates close to what I want. Thank you very much. One more question: how can I keep the order in my csv file? I need 169 rows.

Comment: 169 rows = 1 00,count1 to 7 23,count2;

Comment: @Ashwini... this works. I need to step through it to understand what you did. Thank you!!!

Comment: @chatu I've added some comments so that you can understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for those comments. One more quick question: If I were to clean up my code and replace the master file (f1) with a string variable. How can I do that. My attempt is here:  template = "date, count";

for day in range(1, 8):
    for hour in range(00, 24):
        # Write day + hour, count (0).
        template = template + "\n" + str(day) + " " + str(hour) + "," + "0"; #Thanks.

Comment: @chatu better use string formatting, using `str()` multiple times looks ugly.